# Connect to iDrac Virtual Console programmatically

Tags: server, automation

I frequently connect to the virtual console provided by iDrac on many Dell servers which I manage. I'm looking for a way to connect to the virtual console programmatically, or whatever method that's faster than logging into the web interface manually and going through all the prompts.

Dell's racadm tool does not support this, apparently. iDrac is not set up with domain auth, just using a local account configured on iDrac. I would be connecting from a Windows machine, any browser.

Is there any way to automate this? Even partially?

Answer (score 0):

I use a shell script for this, you can make a .bat file on Windows. See some simple instructions to [start iDrac console from command line here](https://gist.github.com/xbb/4fd651c2493ad9284dbcb827dc8886d6)

Answer (score 0):

see [How to Launch the Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller (iDRAC) Virtual Console](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000179797/dell-poweredge-idrac-virtual-console)

**Summary**: *The iDRAC virtual console can be launched using a web interface or URL. Using the iDRAC virtual console viewer is also explained*